# Java program won't write to firebase

Tags: java, firebase

I have recently been using Firebase to transfer data across networks but the Java program I wrote will not change the data values. I have a firebase app with a tree like this.

```
<MY_WEBSITE>
|=>telemetry
   |=>direction : 0
   |=>speed : 0
```

and the code I'm using to try and write is this.

```
public class telem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Firebase direction;
        direction = new Firebase("https://<MY_WEBSITE>.firebaseio.com/telemetry/direction");
        direction.setValue(1);
    }
}
```

I continued to try using both a thread.sleep and a real-time listener (separately) and the output that returned in the console said that the data change went through, however, when I checked in forge the data had not changed.

Here is the code I used:

```
//CREATE A FIREBASE
        Firebase fb = new Firebase("https://<MY_WEBSITE>.firebaseio.com/telemetry/direction");
        //SAVE DATA
        fb.setValue("1");
        //LISTEN FOR REALTIME CHANGES
        while(true) {
            fb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
                    System.out.println(snap.getKey() + " -> " + snap.getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
                }
            });
        }
```

And here is the response it returned:

```
direction -> 1
```

Comment: Since the write to Firebase happens asynchronously, you'll need to wait for it to complete. This was asked recently, so I'll look up that question and link it to yours.

Comment: Maybe this will get you going somewhere, `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`.

Comment: @Omer: I just noticed your update. Note that listeners fire straight away for local changes, so the fact that the `println` fired is no indication that it was also committed on the server. If you want to be certain of the latter, add a completion listener as documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback